# delete [] performance issues

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, memory-management

I wrote a program, which computes the flow shop scheduling problem.

I need help with optimizing the slowest parts of my program:

Firstly there is array 2D array allocation:

```
this->_perm = new Chromosome*[f];

//... for (...)

this->_perm[i] = new Chromosome[fM1];
```

It works just fine, but a problem occurs, when I try to delete array:

```
delete [] _perm[i];
```

It takes extremely long to execute line above. `Chromosome` is array of about 300k elements - allocating it takes less than a second but deleting takes far more than a minute.

I would appreciate any suggestions of improving delete part.

Comment: Is there something expensive in the destructor of `Chromosome`?

Comment: Well, _perm is 2D array of Chromosome, where each Chromosome is contains array of Gene* genes;. There are as many genes as tasks to schedule. Each Gene contains two arrays: int start[2] and int end[2].

Comment: Obvious question: why do you need these millions of allocations? Why do you need pointers at all? Couldn't it all be stored in a small number of objects, with better cache locality and performance to boot?

Comment: Perchance is there any Disk or other I/O in your constructors or destructors?  That's about the only thing outside of multiple calling of destuctors per element that would lead to such a huge difference in construction and destruction.  Also, what kind of platform is this running on?  PC, embedded?

Answer (score 5):

On a general note, you should ***never manually manage memory*** in C++. This will lead to leaks, double-deletions and all [kinds of nasty inconveniences](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/283251#283251). Use proper resource-handling classes for this. For example, `std::vector` is what you should use for managing a dynamically allocated array.

---

To get back to your problem at hand, you first need to know what `delete [] _perm[i]` does: It calls the destructor for every `Chromosome` object in that array and then frees the memory. Now you do this in a loop, which means this will call ***all*** `Chromosome` destructors and perform `f` deallocations. As was already mentioned in a comment to your question, it is *very* likely that the `Chromosome` ***destructor is the actual culprit***. Try to investigate that.

---

You can, however, change your memory handling to improve the speed of allocation and deallocation. [As Nawaz has shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837354/delete-performance-problem/4837366#4837366), you could allocate ***one big chunk of memory*** and use that. I'd use a `std::vector` for a buffer:

```
void f(std::size_t row, std::size_t col)
{
  int sizeMemory = sizeof(Chromosome) * row * col;
  std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(sizeMemory); //allocation of memory at once!

  vector<Chromosome*> chromosomes(row);

  // use algorithm as shown by Nawaz
  std::size_t j = 0 ;
  for(std::size_t i = 0 ; i < row ; i++ )
  {
      //...
  }

  make_baby(chromosomes); //use chromosomes

  in_place_destruct(chromosomes.begin(), chromosomes.end());

  // automatic freeing of memory holding pointers in chromosomes
  // automatic freeing of buffer memory
}

template< typename InpIt >
void in_place_destruct(InpIt begin, InpIt end)
{
  typedef std::iterator_traits<InpIt>::value_type value_type; // to call dtor
  while(begin != end)
    (begin++)->~value_type(); // call dtor
}
```

However, despite handling all memory through `std::vector` ***this still is not fully exception-safe***, as it needs to call the `Chromosome` destructors explicitly. (If `make_baby()` throws an exception, the function `f()` will be aborted early. While the destructors of the vectors will delete their content, one only contains pointers, and the other treats its content as raw memory. No guard is watching over the actual objects created in that raw memory.)

---

The best solution I can see is to use a ***one-dimensional arrays*** wrapped in a class that allows ***two-dimensional access*** to the elements in that array. (Memory *is* one-dimensional, after all, on current hardware, so the system is already doing this.) Here's a sketch of that:

```
class chromosome_matrix {
public:
  chromosome_matrix(std::size_t row, std::size_t col)
   : row_(row), col_(col), data_(row*col)
  {
    // data_ contains row*col constructed Chromosome objects
  }

  // note needed, compiler generated dtor will do the right thing
  //~chromosome_matrix()

   // these rely on pointer arithmetic to access a column
        Chromosome* operator[](std::size_t row)       {return &data_[row*col_];}
  const Chromosome* operator[](std::size_t row) const {return &data_[row*col_];}

private:
  std::size_t row_;
  std::size_t col_;
  std::vector<chromosomes> data_
};

void f(std::size_t row, std::size_t col)
{
  chromosome_matrix cm(row, col);

  Chromosome* column = ch[0];          // get a whole column
  Chromosome& chromosome1 = column[0]; // get one object

  Chromosome& chromosome2 = cm[1][2];  // access object directly

  // make baby
}
```

Answer (score 4):

check your destructors.

If you were allocating a built-in type (eg an int) then allocating 300,000 of them would be more expensive than the corresponding delete. But that's a relative term, 300k allocated in a single block is pretty fast.

As you're allocating 300k Chromosomes, the allocator has to allocate 300k * sizeof the Chromosome object, and as you say its fast - I can't see it doing much beside just that (ie the constructor calls are optimised into nothingness)

However, when you come to delete, it not only frees up all that memory, but it also calls the destructor for each object, and if its slow, I would guess that the destructor for each object takes a small, but noticeable, time when you have 300k of them.

Comment: If the ctor's performance impact is neglectable, it's not impossible, but rather unusual that the dtor performs anything noticeable.

Comment: not necessarily - there is a paradigm where the ctor is empty, and the object is then initialised after construction via an Initialise call. I've seen it, might even have used it once.

Comment: Even if you have two-phase construction (oh the horror!), initialization _must_ take place somehow. As I said, it's easy to construct samples where initialization is much cheaper then deinitialization, but IME they are rare in practice.

Comment: it depends on your data storage inside the class. It doesn't matter what happens mostly in practice, its what happens in the questioner's class. As he's using new to allocate an array of objects (instead of a vector, say) then I guess he's got POD types in the class so allocation should be as quick as a single malloc! I also assume he's doing a lot of checking, extended cleanup of other objects, or even logging in his dtor that causes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use placement new. The allocation and deallocation can be done just in one  statement each!

```
int sizeMemory = sizeof(Chromosome) * row * col;
char* buffer = new char[sizeMemory]; //allocation of memory at once!

vector<Chromosome*> chromosomes;
chromosomes.reserve(row);
int j = 0 ;
for(int i = 0 ; i < row ; i++ )
{
    //only construction of object. No allocation!
    Chromosome *pChromosome = new (&buffer[j]) Chromosome[col]; 
    chromosomes.push_back(pChromosome);
    j = j+ sizeof(Chromosome) * col;
}

for(int i = 0 ; i < row ; i++ )
{
      for(int j = 0 ; j < col ; j++ )
      {
         //only destruction of object. No deallocation!
         chromosomes[i][j].~Chromosome();
      }
}
delete [] buffer; //actual deallocation of memory at once!
```

Comment: The problem is that I cannot everything at once - that is why I have to use delete in same loop as I used new. My program firstly was genetic algorithm for Flow Shop but now I am writing brute force on the same structures (cause most of representation remains unchanged). For 5 tasks there are factorial(nTasks) * factorial(nTasks+ (nTasks- 1)) possibilities - I have no sufficient RAM to allocate it all at once

Comment: @Overpain: Memory allocation and deallocation can be done at once. Atleast this part can be made fast, without much knowing your situation. Everything else is under your control. You can call destructor for objects at your will; you can delete them one by one also!

Comment: @Nawaz: I have no idea whether the `Chromosome` ctor might throw, and even less so about the code that's actually using these chromosomes. That's why I'd insist on an exception-safe solution. (And even if the code can never throw now, it might after maintenance.) You cannot easily make this exception-safe, as the loop to destruct all objects need to be executed. The best way to solve this is to put that loop into a class' destructor. But once you do this, you might just as well make the two-dimensional access a pure wrapper around a one-dimensional array. See my answer.

Comment: @sbi: But you've to destruct the objects anyway; so it confuses me when you say that it's not exception-safe if I destruct the objects in a loop. Could you please further explain how exactly it is different from putting this loop in a class's destructor?

Comment: @Nawaz: All your code does is to construct all those objects, and then destruct them immediately. For one, if one of the ctors throws, you would have to call the dtors of all the objects constructed so far, but not of those that never got constructed. Further, in between construction and destruction there will likely be code _using_ these objects. That might throw, too, in which case all objects need to have their dtor called. In both cases your code would destruct none of the objects. That is _wrong_ - and  especially so, since the memory they're residing in will be destructed automatically.

Comment: @sbi: what you said makes sense now. But mine is not complete solution; this is just a start as to how he could go. how to construct objects, how to destruct them; he can wrap these code in a wrapper class and so on. It's not a complete solution; how can it be; after all, my code does nothing with the objects created. I'm just demonstrating the syntax part, related to memory allocation, deallocation, object construction, and destruction!

Answer (score 0):

std::vector can help.

Special memory allocators too.